# Qt ActiveX Server Debugging Strategy

Tags: c++, qt, activex, activex-exe

I am having problems with building an ActiveX object via activeqt.  I attempted to follow a "Simple Example" via the qt 5 documentation ([source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/activeqt/activeqt-simple.html), but when I run the demo IE page, the page only displays "Object not available!  Did you forget to build and register the server?".  My steps consisted of the following:

1. Install Visual Studio 2012 Express
2. Install Qt creator with extra sources (64 bit on 64 bit Windows 7)
3. Build the QAxServer library
4. Run qmake on the Simple example project
5. Build the "Simple" example project
6. Try the page with IE

I verified the classid is at least showing in the registry, and the compile output notes that activex server was successfully registered.  I checked the event logs, but nothing is showing.  The IE console notes that the "Object doesn't support property or method 'about'", but I get that error even if I use a bogus class id, so I'm assuming it could be throwing that error for many reasons.  Does anybody have any other debugging strategies?  Anywhere else IE might be hiding some useful logs?  Thanks!